# How to fetch aria-label as text on basis of div id in Python using Beautiful or Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
<div id="i19" class="quantumWizTogglePapercheckboxEl appsMaterialWizTogglePapercheckboxCheckbox docssharedWizToggleLabeledControl freebirdThemedCheckbox freebirdThemedCheckboxDarkerDisabled freebirdMaterialWidgetsToggleLabeledCheckbox isCheckedNext isChecked" jscontroller="EcW08c" jsaction="keydown:I481le;dyRcpb:dyRcpb;click:cOuCgd; mousedown:UX7yZ; mouseup:lbsD7e; mouseenter:tfO1Yc; mouseleave:JywGue; focus:AHmuwe; blur:O22p3e; contextmenu:mg9Pef;touchstart:p6p2H; touchmove:FwuNnf; touchend:yfqBxc(preventMouseEvents=true|preventDefault=true); touchcancel:JMtRjd;" jsshadow="" jsname="FkQz1b" aria-label="Al-Baraka Bank Limited" data-answer-value="Al-Baraka Bank (Pakistan) Limited" role="checkbox" aria-checked="true" tabindex="0">
```

Hi, im trying to fetch the text that is placed inside the aria-label in this div `Al-Baraka Bank Limited` with the div id `i19`. Basically i am clicking on a checkbox and i want the text i.e aria-label to be saved to a variable so i can use it again in some other place.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What problems, errors faced there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that **id** is `unique`, then you can do `get_attribute` to get the attribute value.

```
aria_label = driver.find_element(By.ID, "i19").get_attribute('aria-label')
print(aria_label)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have taken your data as `html` you can find `div` based on id and then extract attributes of it

```
html="""<div id="i19" class="quantumWizTogglePapercheckboxEl appsMaterialWizTogglePapercheckboxCheckbox docssharedWizToggleLabeledControl freebirdThemedCheckbox freebirdThemedCheckboxDarkerDisabled freebirdMaterialWidgetsToggleLabeledCheckbox isCheckedNext isChecked" jscontroller="EcW08c" jsaction="keydown:I481le;dyRcpb:dyRcpb;click:cOuCgd; mousedown:UX7yZ; mouseup:lbsD7e; mouseenter:tfO1Yc; mouseleave:JywGue; focus:AHmuwe; blur:O22p3e; contextmenu:mg9Pef;touchstart:p6p2H; touchmove:FwuNnf; touchend:yfqBxc(preventMouseEvents=true|preventDefault=true); touchcancel:JMtRjd;" jsshadow="" jsname="FkQz1b" aria-label="Al-Baraka Bank Limited" data-answer-value="Al-Baraka Bank (Pakistan) Limited" role="checkbox" aria-checked="true" tabindex="0">
"""
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")
soup.find("div",attrs={"id":"i19"})['aria-label']
```

Output:

```
'Al-Baraka Bank Limited'
```

OR:

Also it returns as dictinory so you can find based on key to extract values from it!

```
soup.find("div",attrs={"id":"i19"}).attrs
```